How could my android app work in the background and send notifications without having to launch it?
I have a simple app that reads battery value from SystemServices and it's supposed to alert user when the battery reaches 25% or when it's charging over 80%.
How could it alert the user with notifications without having to be launched constantly?
Would I need push notifications, IntentServices, or how could I best go about it?
For the test, I have only implemented local notifications inside the app so far. But that's not the wanted end result.
Thanks!
Also, I'm using Jetpack Compose if that's important.
Here's the code for the Service:
package com.example.batterymanager

import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.app.Service
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.IBinder
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat


class BatteryService: Service() {
    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        when(intent?.action) {
            Actions.START.toString() -> start()
            Actions.STOP.toString() -> stopSelf()
        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
    }

   private fun start() {
       val perNotification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "newChannel")
           .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
           .setContentTitle("Monitoring your battery")
           .setContentText("Taking care of your battery because you don't")
           .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
           .build()
        startForeground(1, perNotification)
    }

    enum class Actions {
        START, STOP
    }

}


Notification classes for both persistent service Notification and the alert notification :
package com.example.batterymanager

import android.app.Application
import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Build

class MyApp: Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

      
        val name = "Battery State"
        val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
        val descriptionText = "This is the important state of your battery"

         if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
             val channel = NotificationChannel("channelID", name, importance).apply {description = descriptionText}
             val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
             notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }

        val newName = "Service"
        val newImportance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
        val newDescription = "This is your background service"

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val newChannel = NotificationChannel("newChannel", newName, newImportance). apply {
                description = newDescription
            }
           val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(newChannel)
        }


    }
}


And Main Activity:
package com.example.batterymanager



import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.BatteryManager
import android.os.BatteryManager.BATTERY_PROPERTY_CAPACITY
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material3.Button
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalContext
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat
import com.example.batterymanager.ui.theme.BatteryManagerTheme


class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                arrayOf( android.Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS),
                0

            )
        }
        setContent {
            BatteryManagerTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    val context = LocalContext.current
                    val batteryManager = context.getSystemService(BATTERY_SERVICE) as BatteryManager
                    val batteryLevel = batteryManager.getIntProperty(BATTERY_PROPERTY_CAPACITY)


                    Column(Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
                    ) {



                        Button(onClick = {
                            Intent(applicationContext, BatteryService::class.java).also {
                                it.action = BatteryService.Actions.START.toString()
                                startService(it)
                            }

                        }) {
                            Text(text = "Start service")
                        }
                        Button(onClick = {
                            Intent(applicationContext, BatteryService::class.java).also {
                                it.action = BatteryService.Actions.STOP.toString()
                                startService(it)
                            }
                        }) {
                            Text(text = "Stop service")
                        }


                    }

                    fun showLowNotification() {
                        val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
                        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext, "channelID")
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                            .setContentTitle("Battery low!")
                            .setContentText("Your phone is at 25%! Charge it now!")
                            .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
                            .setAutoCancel(true)
                            .build()
                        notificationManager.notify(1, notification)

                    }

                    fun show80Notification() {
                        val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
                        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext, "channelID")
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                            .setContentTitle("Battery at 80!")
                            .setContentText("Your phone is at 80%! Stop charging it!")
                            .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
                            .setAutoCancel(true)
                            .build()
                        notificationManager.notify(1, notification)

                    }

                    if (batteryLevel <= 25) {

                            showLowNotification()

                    }

                    if (batteryLevel >= 80) {

                            show80Notification()

                    }





                }
            }
        }
    }
}





Have you read https://developer.android.com/develop/background-work/services? Can you explain why this doesn't work for you?

I haven't tried implementing anything yet, just asking what exactly would be the optimal way to do what I want without complicating things. I'll look into that and get back to you. Thank you!
